# python unpacking arg list with *args and **kwargs along with other positional and keyword only params

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have this following function defined in a file named kwargs.py. (changing the module to unpacking.py made the function work as expected). See the image at the bottom of the question.

```
def tag(name, *content, cls=None, **attrs):
    if cls is not None:
        attrs['class'] = cls
    
    if attrs:
        attr_str = ''.join(' %s="%s"' % (key,val) 
                                         for key, val 
                                         in sorted(attrs.items()))
    else:
        attr_str = ''
    
    if content:
        return '\n'.join('<%s%s>%s</%s>' % (name,attr_str,c,name) for c in content)
    else:
        return '<%s%s />' % (name,attr_str)
```

when executing this

```
tag('div', 'testing', cls='test', **dict(id=33,alt='this is a test'))
```

The result i get is

```
'<div alt="this is a test" class="test" id="33">testing</div>'
```

But when i execute this

```
tag(**dict(name='div', content=('testing','and testing'), cls='test', id=33, alt='this is a test'))
```

i only get

```
'<div alt="this is a test" class="test" id="33" />'
```

why is the parameter `name` getting assigned but not `content`. (Even if the tuple is not unpacked i was expecting at least the tuple itself be assigned to content[0]).

What am i missing here?

Edit:
*Python 3.8.3 x86 in Windows 10*
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First let's make sure we are using the same terminology:

- A function declares *parameters* (`name, *content, cls=None, **attrs` in your example),
- A function call receives *arguments* (e.g. `'div', 'testing', cls='test', **dict(id=33, alt='this is a test')`).

The arguments are then bound to the parameters, so they can be accessed in the function body.

First let's look at the function signature:

```py
def tag(name, *content, cls=None, **attrs):
    ...
```

This function defines four parameters:

- `name` - a positional-or-keyword parameter,
- `content` - a varargs-parameter which captures any number of additional *positional* arguments,
- `cls` - a keyword-only parameter with a default value,
- `attrs` - a keywords-parameter which captures any number of additional *keyword* arguments.

When you call this function in the following way this is what happens:

```py
tag('div', 'testing', cls='test', **dict(id=33, alt='this is a test'))
```

- `'div'` is bound to `name`,
- `'testing'` is captured by `content` resulting in a 1-tuple,
- `'test'` is bound to `cls`,
- `id=33, alt='this is a test'` are captured by `attrs`.

Now the special thing about the `*content` and `**attrs` parameters is that they capture any number of excess arguments but they can't be bound to directly. I.e. you can't bind `content=(1, 2)`. Instead if you pass `tag('foo', 1, 2)` this binding happens automatically. So if you call the function in the following way:

```py
tag(**dict(name='div', content=('testing', 'and testing'), cls='test', id=33, alt='this is a test'))
```

Then all arguments are provided by keyword and hence all except `name` and `cls` are captured by `attrs`. This is because `*content` only captures *positional* arguments.

Comment: You are right and I understood it in this way precisely. But the problem was that ```content=('testing', 'and testing')``` was not assigned to the param **kwargs. That's what prompted me to post this question. The accepted answer told me to change my module name as i had named it as "kwargs.py". After changing the name to "unpacking.py" the same example i posted worked as expected.

Comment: If you could explain why the module name caused this problem it will be much appreciated. In fact the module name didn't cause the entire kwargs parameter to be unusable. It only masked the tuple argument (with the same name as the variable argument param) from being mapped . It worked if the name was something else in the argument dict.

Comment: @ThirumalaiParthasarathi In your question I don't see any mention of this module `kwargs.py` and also the `tag` function doesn't declare a parameter with that name. So it's not clear how they would interact. Could you please provide more information by updating your question?

Comment: I think it'd be better to ask another question where `kwargs.py` contents is listed instead of editing question name and body.

Comment: @a_guest the param name is not kwargs. I'm sorry for the confusion. only the module's name is kwargs.

Comment: @TomaszWojcik I believe this is still the same question as the function is the only thing existing in the module.

Comment: @ThirumalaiParthasarathi I'm not sure why the module name would have an influence on how the `tag` function works. Also I cannot reproduce the behavior that your screenshot suggests. For me the `content` is included as an attribute of the HTML tag. Please update your question with a number of precise steps that allow for reproducing the problem, starting at the very beginning with creating that module all the way down to using it. Otherwise it's difficult to make any assumptions on what's going on.

Comment: It is my mistake. I had been executing a wrong version of my file where i had a filter after the sorted() function call. That is why the pair was getting skipped. It didn't have anything to do with the module name. Sorry was wasting your time!

Comment: @ThirumalaiParthasarathi That makes sense. When modifying a module on disk you need to call [`importlib.reload(kwargs)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#importlib.reload) to make the changes effective in a running interpreter session, just doing `import kwargs` again will only fetch the module's old version from the [`sys.modules`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.modules) cache.

Comment: Just now realized that as well. Perhaps you can add that to your answer as well. I had to close my interpreter session and reopen it to understand that problem :)

Comment: @ThirumalaiParthasarathi I think that's out of scope for this question, even if it was the root cause of your problem. As the question stands, it doesn't include multiple versions of one module.

Answer (score 2):

`*content` is not an argument. You can't assign anything to it.

The docs indeed don't explain it explicitly. It's just a variable that you can use within your function body. What it does is "it scoops up all remaining input arguments".

> Normally, these variadic arguments will be last in the list of formal parameters, because they scoop up all remaining input arguments that are passed to the function.

https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#arbitrary-argument-lists

This function

```
def func(*args, **kwargs):
    print("args", args)
    print("kwargs", kwargs)


func(args=[1, 2, 3])
```

will print

```
args ()
kwargs {'args': [1, 2, 3]}
```

EDIT:

Your examples are wrong. You can't get a different output.

For this function

```
def tag(name, *content, cls=None, **attrs):
    if cls is not None:
        attrs['class'] = cls
    if attrs:
        attr_str = ''.join(' %s="%s"' % (key, val)
                           for key, val
                           in sorted(attrs.items()))
    else:
        attr_str = ''

    if content:
        resp = '\n'.join('<%s%s>%s</%s>' % (name, attr_str, c, name) for c in content)
    else:
        resp = '<%s%s />' % (name, attr_str)

    print("name", name)
    print("*content", content)
    print("cls", cls)
    print("attrs", attrs)
    print("attrs_str", attr_str)
    print("resp", resp)
    print('-'*10)
   
    return resp
```

If you run this

```
tag('div', 'testing', cls='test', **dict(id=33, alt='this is a test'))
tag(**dict(name='div', content=('testing','and testing'), cls='test', id=33, alt='this is a test'))
```

You get

```
name div
*content ('testing',)
cls test
attrs {'id': 33, 'alt': 'this is a test', 'class': 'test'}
attrs_str  alt="this is a test" class="test" id="33"
resp <div alt="this is a test" class="test" id="33">testing</div>
----------
name div
*content ()
cls test
attrs {'content': ('testing', 'and testing'), 'id': 33, 'alt': 'this is a test', 'class': 'test'}
attrs_str  alt="this is a test" class="test" content="('testing', 'and testing')" id="33"
resp <div alt="this is a test" class="test" content="('testing', 'and testing')" id="33" />
----------
```

So you shouldn't get `'<div alt="this is a test" class="test" id="33" />'` for the second case. I get `<div alt="this is a test" class="test" content="('testing', 'and testing')" id="33" />` for the exactly same function.

EDIT 2: Probably your namespace is broken as name `**kwargs` is often used somewhere else in a way you use `**attrs` here so changing this module name / importing function directly should solve your issue.

Comment: if that is the case then why wasn't the dict entry captured by kwargs? I'm quite not satisfied with your explanation.

Comment: Why not? You allow for `**kwargs` and all of `cls='test', **dict(id=33,alt='this is a test')` will be passed as a key value to the function. Content has been passed as a `content` to kwargs. If you do `attrs.get('content')` you will see it there.

Comment: ```attr_str = ''.join(' %s="%s"' % (key,val) for key, val in sorted(attrs.items()))``` does print all the dict entries. But as i pointed out in the result it is not being printed as such.

Comment: I get a different output than you for the exact same code. Added after editing my answer.

Comment: I see your point but that is what i'm getting in my machine. I have updated my version info. Perhaps i shall upload a snip of my console too.

Comment: I can't believe version has something to do with this. Maybe once you identify the difference ask a different question.

Comment: `kwargs.tag` ? your namespace is broken for sure. Name it differently. Don't use `attrs` for `kwargs` as it's a python module and `kwargs` for namespace as it's usually `**attrs`. Run it directly. There's something wrong with how you run your function for sure.

Comment: It doesn't matter what you believe my friend. If you can't believe different versions of software exhibiting different behavior then i can't say anything no more. :)

Comment: perhaps you are right about the namespace. Let me try that and get back to you.

Comment: You are right. It works when i change the module name to something else. Would you like to update your answer with this info so that i can accept it?

Comment: @TomaszWojcik Why would it matter how the keywords (`**`) parameter is named? I can't follow your logic here. You can give it any name as long as it's a valid identifier. Also the module name doesn't matter. @ThirumalaiParthasarathi Something else seems to be going on, I suggest your provide all details on how to reproduce that problem.